# Disabling Ionic 2 keyboard for ion-input

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I am using [ionic date time picker](https://github.com/misha130/datepicker-ionic2) for my project, basically i am facing two problems here

1. calendar opens up only on two consecutive clicks, i want it to open up on single click
2. keyboard opens up for the first click which i want to disable to prevent user from entering date manually.

   ```
   <ion-row>
           <ion-col>
                   <ion-item id="clickTwoTimes" ion-datepicker (ionChanged)="setStartDate($event);" [value]="localStartDate" full="true" clearclass="ScheduleDate">

                        <ion-input disabled name="Date" placeholder="Start Date" [ngModel]="localStartDate | date" (ngModelChange)="localStartDate=$event">
                        </ion-input>

                </ion-item>
          </ion-col>


         <ion-col>
             <ion-item ion-datepicker (ionChanged)="setEndDate($event);" [value]="localEndDate" full="true" clear class="ScheduleDate">

                    <ion-input [disabled]='true' name="Date" placeholder="End Date" [ngModel]="localEndDate | date" (ngModelChange)="localEndDate=$event">
                   </ion-input>
             </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
   ```

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @ViniciusZilliPavei no ,unfortunately it was not able to find a fix so i switched to ionic default time picker -https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/.